# Pass mouse events to applications behind from a Java UI

Tags: java, events, mouse, transparency

The question I have is exactly same in requirement as [How to pass mouse events to applications behind mine in C#/Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173579/how-to-pass-mouse-events-to-applications-behind-mine-in-c-vista) , but I need the same for a Transparent Java UI. I can easily create a transparent Java UI using 6.0 but couldn't get any info about passing events through the app to any applications(say a browser) behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this will answer your question. To run it you will need Java 6 update 10 and above.
I tested it on Windows Vista

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ClickThrough {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        Component c = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                g2.setColor(Color.gray);
                int w = getWidth();
                int h = getHeight();
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, w,h);
                g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
                g2.fillRect(w/4, h/4, w-2*(w/4), h-2*(h/4));
            }
        };
        c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        f.getContentPane().add(c);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(f,false);
    }

}
```

Note that you need to either have an undecorated window or one that is decorated by Java alone (not the default OS decoration) otherwise the code won't work.

Comment: seems to allow click through well with jdk 1.6, 1.7 on windows 7, jdk 1.6, 1.7 on XP. Not sure about other OS's though...

Comment: This is a dangerous example as it attempts to "fake" transparency on an opaque component which could result in graphics ghosting and other graphics artifacts.  I better and simpler solution would have been to simply make the `Component` `c` transparent by using `setOpaue` and passing it `false`.  You've also broken the paint chain

Answer (score 2):

Savvas' answer helped me perfectly even on MacOS X 10.7.3 using Java 1.6.0_31. Thanks!
The only thing: I additionally had to set

```
f.setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: I found this necessary to run without exceptions on OS X 10.9 with Java 1.7.0_4, but the transparent area **did not allow click events to pass through** to the applications beneath.

Comment: This appears to be a platform-dependent issue and is also noted at https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8013450 and at http://stackoverflow.com/q/13020607/186818

Answer (score 2):

**This is not answer, but an update which corrects dangerous issues to the accepted answer as well as providing an example compatible with Java 7+**

Per-Pixel alphering checks each pixel in the window to determine if it's transparent or not.  If it's transparent, then the mouse events are allowed to pass through it, if its is not transparent, the mouse events will be caught by the window.  This is generally an OS level issue.

The example is you provide is actually doing some very dangerous things, first it's painting a translucent color onto a opaque component, this means that Swing doesn't know that it should actually be painting anything under the component and could also result in a number of very nasty paint artifacts, as Swing only knows about opaque and transparent component, it doesn't know about semi-transparent components, so you need to trick the API.

When performing custom painting, you should always call `super.paintComponent` to ensure that the `Graphics` context is setup correctly before painting.  In your case, you should also make the component transparent using `setOpaque` and passing it `false`

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    public TestFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
            g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Robot Class http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html which allows you to specify system events to the low level operating system, specifically things like mouse events.

Comment: Robot can be used for generating system events but if my transparent frame is already at the location where i need to click, wouldn't the java frame again receive the event?

Comment: you can catch the even at the glass pane (read the java tutorial for this) and then simply consume the event.

Comment: you can temporarily hide the window. it will introduce some flicker i know but i cant think of something else....

Comment: Just because you have changed the opacity of the window does not mean the events get transferred through.  you would then need to fire the events using the robot class.