# Is it possible to have a translucent windows in java 7 including a title bar?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, java-7, translucency

Related to this question:
[Is The Java Tutorials Translucent Window example giving trouble to those playing with jdk7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259269/is-the-java-tutorials-translucent-window-example-giving-trouble-to-those-playing)

with jdk1.6.0_26 I seem to be able to apply translucency to a JFrame, but not so with jre7:

NativeException: java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated

ex (jruby scripting java, works jdk1.6 not with jdk7 though):

```
require 'java'

class MouseDraw

  def self.go
    java_import 'javax.swing.JFrame'
    java_import 'com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities'

    f = JFrame.new
    AWTUtilities.set_window_opacity(f, 0.5)
    f.set_size 200,200
    f.show
  end

end
MouseDraw.go
```

So my question is "is it possible to have a translucent title bar in jdk7" (I would like a transparent window I'm creating to be draggable/resizable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 7 introduced [`Window.setOpacity()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setOpacity%28float%29) to do what the unofficial class `AWTUtilities` did in Java 6.

Unfortunately it's documented not to work with decorated windows:

> The following conditions must be met in order to set the opacity value less than `1.0f`:
>
> - The [`TRANSLUCENT`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.html#TRANSLUCENT) translucency must be supported by the underlying system
> - **The window must be undecorated** (see [`Frame.setUndecorated(boolean)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) and [`Dialog.setUndecorated(boolean)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29))
> - The window must not be in full-screen mode (see [`GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(Window)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow%28java.awt.Window%29))

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: @kleopatra: but that's what you signed up for when you used unofficial API: The `AWTUtilities` are not defined in Java SE and the new method doesn't break compatibility with any previously defined public method.

Comment: technically, you'r right, also technically, I didn't: instead used the AWTUtilitiesWrapper which was a half-official preview of the to-be functionality (and advertised as rather safe ;-)

Comment: judging from the tutorial being outdated, this looks (wild guess) like a rather late emergency brake for some wild or not so wild side-effect in decorated windows (bye bye fading out ;-)

Comment: So I have a java 7 program that uses decorated windows that are translucent (and it works on ubuntu). Then running the same program on windows doesn't work. explain that one.

Comment: @JoelBoulet: I don't really know what you expect. I think you should post this as a question with a bit more information to it.

Answer (score 3):

Fascinatingly, if you add

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

Then it allows you to have a draggable, with title bar JFrame (it just uses the ugly java look and feel).

ref: [Pass mouse events to applications behind from a Java UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190168/pass-mouse-events-to-applications-behind-from-a-java-ui)

Now that is weird.

Also note that you can "fake" the old behavior using per pixel transparency, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

so you can have the old behavior in both java 6 and 7, but you'd have to special case the code around it and do it one way for one, one way for the other, possibly...