# Transparent JFrame/JWindow on Mac OSX with Java 7

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe, transparent

We have a screen sharing applet that opens up a Swing JFrame and uses the Robot class to capture the screen behind the empty frame.

The user is able to click through the frame and interact with whatever lies behind the applet.
This works fine on Windows and used to work with Apple's Java version, but with Java 7 for Mac it does not work. Mouse clicks does not go through the JFrame.

The JFrame uses:

```
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
setUndecorated(true);
```

Tried using:

```
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(false);
```

Or

```
setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

With Apple's version the:

```
getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", Boolean.FALSE);
```

Call did the trick, but this is no longer working.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Eilon

Comment: Try posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner...

Comment: Did anyone found a solution to this issue?

Comment: not sure when it was fixed, but it works for me in java with this code: http://alvinalexander.com/source-code/java/how-create-transparenttranslucent-java-jframe-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

It's bug in jdk 7(will be fixed in jdk 9). There only way to use jdk 6.

[link to bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8013450)

P.s. have you find any solution of this problem?

Comment: @JeroenKetelaar I used jdk 6 for Mac.

Comment: yea that works, although the majority uses Java 7 these days, so I'm not able to write something for others while this issue occurs. Thanks for the update though!