# Non-transparent click-through window in Win32

Tags: winapi, window, click-through

Is it possible in Win32 to create non-transparent window, which is click-through (sends click events to what lays below)? I tried to catch `WM_NCHITTEST` message and return `HTTRANSPARENT`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest):n a window currently covered by another window in the same thread (the message will be sent to underlying windows in the same thread until one of them returns a code that is not HTTRANSPARENT).So to process the `WM_NCHITTEST` message you need to ensure that the windows are in the same thread.And you can refer to : [Letting the mouse pass through Windows C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069717/letting-the-mouse-pass-through-windows-c)

Comment: Unfortunately my intention is to pass through the clicks to any window, not only one, which belongs to the same thread. The idea is to have full-screen, on top window, which is transparent for clicks. The window is going to apply some graphical effect on what is underneath and display it within its client area.

Comment: Could you please show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information?