# Make a win32 window transparent to messages (click, touch, keyboard)

Tags: winapi, win32gui

I created a semi transparent window using the source code from this discussion (posted by wilkie):
[How to make an OpenGL rendering context with transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052940/how-to-make-an-opengl-rendering-context-with-transparent-background)

It works, but I would like my window not to pick up mouse, touch and keyboard click messages.
But above all, I would like these messages (click, touch, keyboard) to be received by the application located below my transparent window.

Example:
My transparent window (TOP_MOST) is located on top of NotePad ++. If I click on my transparent window, I want this click to be received by NotePad++ and not by my transparent window.

I did not find valid answers on the Internet.
I see two possibilities:
_ Make my window transparent to all messages
_ Or my transparent window must receive the messages, not react and redirect them by sending them to the window located below.

In both cases, I don't know how to do it :)
Is it possible ?

Regards,

Edit with code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#include <dwmapi.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")

#pragma comment (lib, "dwmapi.lib")

#include <assert.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#ifdef  assert
#define verify(expr) if(!expr) assert(0)
#else verify(expr) expr
#endif

const TCHAR szAppName[] = _T("TransparentGL");
const TCHAR wcWndName[] = _T("TransparentGL");

HDC hDC;
HGLRC m_hrc;
int w = 240;
int h = 240;

BOOL initSC() {
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}

void resizeSC(int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

BOOL renderSC() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                              // Drawing Using Triangles
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);                      // Set The Color To Red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                      // Set The Color To Green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);                      // Set The Color To Blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    return 0;
}

BOOL CreateHGLRC(HWND hWnd) {
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,                                // Version Number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |         // Format Must Support Window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |         // Format Must Support OpenGL
        PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION |         // Format Must Support Composition
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                 // Must Support Double Buffering
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                    // Request An RGBA Format
        32,                               // Select Our Color Depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                 // Color Bits Ignored
        8,                                // An Alpha Buffer
        0,                                // Shift Bit Ignored
        0,                                // No Accumulation Buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,                       // Accumulation Bits Ignored
        24,                               // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)
        8,                                // Some Stencil Buffer
        0,                                // No Auxiliary Buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                   // Main Drawing Layer
        0,                                // Reserved
        0, 0, 0                           // Layer Masks Ignored
    };

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    int PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
    if (PixelFormat == 0) {
        assert(0);
        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL bResult = SetPixelFormat(hdc, PixelFormat, &pfd);
    if (bResult == FALSE) {
        assert(0);
        return FALSE;
    }

    m_hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
    if (!m_hrc) {
        assert(0);
        return FALSE;
    }

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {


    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (m_hrc) {
            wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
            wglDeleteContext(m_hrc);
        }
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR str, int nWinMode) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowFunc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hThisInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(0x00000000);
    wc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("RegisterClassEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, szAppName, wcWndName,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 200, 150, w, h,
        NULL, NULL, hThisInst, NULL);

    if (!hWnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("CreateWindowEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    DWM_BLURBEHIND bb = { 0 };
    HRGN hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
    bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
    bb.hRgnBlur = hRgn;
    bb.fEnable = TRUE;
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd, &bb);

    CreateHGLRC(hWnd);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, m_hrc);
    initSC();
    resizeSC(w, h);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

    MSG msg;
    while (1) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else {
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            wglMakeCurrent(hdc, m_hrc);

            renderSC();

            SwapBuffers(hdc);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        }
    }

    return (FALSE);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165136/ws-ex-transparent-what-does-it-actually-do

Comment: Thanks, but i have already tried to use WS_EX_TRANSPARENT and it doesn't work. I use CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,...).

Comment: Clearly it does work, otherwise it wouldn't exist. There must be something wrong somewhere in your code.

Comment: I have just used the code from "How to make an OpenGL rendering context with transparent background?" (wilkie version). And i have just added "WS_EX_TRANSPARENT" in CreateWindowEx(). Do i have to do something else ? In WindowFunc() ? or in the PeekMessageLoop() ?

Comment: Show a [mcve] please

Comment: I have edited my first post.

Comment: @Greg have you tried processing `WM_NCHITTEST` to return `HTTRANSPARENT` in your transparent areas?  Or, using the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style with `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` or `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to let Windows handle the transparency for you?

Comment: No, i have tried but i don't know how to succed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [`WS_EX_LAYERED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) style when creating the form, and set the opacity of the window through the [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) function.

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED |  WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, szAppName, wcWndName,
WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 200, 150, w, h,
NULL, NULL, hThisInst, NULL);
if (!hWnd) {
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("CreateWindowEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return FALSE;
}
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);
```

Then it works for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to modify the code of the sample to use WS_EX_LAYERED and SetLayeredWindowAttributes but it do not display anything anymore. I think i have to modify other part of the sample to make it work, but i don't know win32 enought to solve the problem.

Comment: @Greg *"it do not display anything anymore"*, I have not reproduced such a problem, can you provide a sample of your code so that I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry. It works, i had modified an bad sample. Thanks ! :)

Comment: @Greg Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zhu Song - MSFT and David Heffernan, this is the full source code of the modified sample originaly posted in this post:
[How to make an OpenGL rendering context with transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052940/how-to-make-an-opengl-rendering-context-with-transparent-background)

It display an OpenGL Triangle in transparente Window and support Click-Through:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#include <dwmapi.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")

#pragma comment (lib, "dwmapi.lib")

#include <assert.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#ifdef  assert
#define verify(expr) if(!expr) assert(0)
#else verify(expr) expr
#endif

const TCHAR szAppName[] = _T("TransparentGL");
const TCHAR wcWndName[] = _T("TransparentGL");

HDC hDC;
HGLRC m_hrc;
int w = 240;
int h = 240;

BOOL initSC() {
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}

void resizeSC(int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

BOOL renderSC() {
    static float angle = 0.0f;
    angle = (angle < 360.0f ) ? angle + 0.01f : 0.0f;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                              // Drawing Using Triangles
    glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.5f);                      // Set The Color To Red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top
    glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);                      // Set The Color To Green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
    glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);                      // Set The Color To Blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    return 0;
}

BOOL CreateHGLRC(HWND hWnd) {
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,                                // Version Number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |         // Format Must Support Window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |         // Format Must Support OpenGL
        PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION |         // Format Must Support Composition
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                 // Must Support Double Buffering
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                    // Request An RGBA Format
        32,                               // Select Our Color Depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                 // Color Bits Ignored
        8,                                // An Alpha Buffer
        0,                                // Shift Bit Ignored
        0,                                // No Accumulation Buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,                       // Accumulation Bits Ignored
        24,                               // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)
        8,                                // Some Stencil Buffer
        0,                                // No Auxiliary Buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                   // Main Drawing Layer
        0,                                // Reserved
        0, 0, 0                           // Layer Masks Ignored
    };

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    int PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
    if (PixelFormat == 0) {
        assert(0);
        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL bResult = SetPixelFormat(hdc, PixelFormat, &pfd);
    if (bResult == FALSE) {
        assert(0);
        return FALSE;
    }

    m_hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
    if (!m_hrc) {
        assert(0);
        return FALSE;
    }

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowFunc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (msg) {

    case WM_CREATE:
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (m_hrc) {
            wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
            wglDeleteContext(m_hrc);
        }
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR str, int nWinMode) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowFunc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hThisInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(0x00000000);
    wc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("RegisterClassEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, szAppName, wcWndName,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 200, 150, w, h,
        NULL, NULL, hThisInst, NULL);
    if (!hWnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("CreateWindowEx - failed"), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);

    DWM_BLURBEHIND bb = { 0 };
    HRGN hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
    bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
    bb.hRgnBlur = hRgn;
    bb.fEnable = TRUE;
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd, &bb);

    CreateHGLRC(hWnd);

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, m_hrc);
    initSC();
    resizeSC(w, h);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

    MSG msg;
    while (1) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else {
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            wglMakeCurrent(hdc, m_hrc);

            renderSC();

            SwapBuffers(hdc);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        }
    }

    return (FALSE);
}
```

If it can help other peoples, if you want to do the same thing with QT:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    _glWidget = new MyOpenGLWidget(this); // derived from: public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core

   setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodTransparent);
   setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
   setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
   SetForegroundWindow((HWND)winId());
   setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint |Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(_glWidget);                      
}
```